# Regex to match 3-digit number and signs and no match

Tags: regex

I've been playing with a regex definition (language "Basic") but cannot get it to work. 
I will delete my previous post on the same matter when I get a solution.

The regex shall:

MATCH: 
"400:-"
"200:-"
"588:-"
"999:-"

BUT NO MATCH: 
"1 200:-"
"o 100:-"
"1400:-"
"y 800:-"
"400"
"i 588:-"

Why does this regex not work? 
(^[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]:-$)

Comment: You say `language "Basic"`. Do you mean VB.Net?

Answer (score 4):

Just try with following regex:

```
^\d{3}:-$
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it without the "^" sign?

Comment: @user3214294 You can use `\D` instead of `^`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
"^[0-9]{3}:-"
```

That tells it to find any number between 0 and 9 three times, at the beginning of the string, followed immediately by ":-"

If you don't want it to check just the beginning then

```
bool check;
Regex reg = new Regex("[0-9]{3}:-");
check = reg.IsMatch("400:-"); // true
check = reg.IsMatch("40:-"); // false
check = reg.IsMatch("asdf400:-"); // true
```

But this will make it match the ones you don't want matched.

Comment: Is it possible to make it without the "^" sign?

Comment: I think it's best to keep the `^` sign since it denotes that it has to be at the beginning of the string, although if that's not a requirement you could remove it and it would work

Comment: When I remove the "^", I also get match on "000:-" derived from "7000:-" as well as "200:-" derived from "1200:-". I dont want that...

Comment: Like I mentioned in my post, removing the `^` anchor tells it to match 3 numbers followed by a ":-" anywhere in the string. I don't see what the difference between "1 200:-" (what you don't want matched) and "400:-" (what you want matched) other than one seems to be at the beginning of a string.

Comment: So to answer your question, no, you can't remove the `^` based on the requirements you provided.

Comment: To somewhat help your case, you could use a word boundary `\b([0-9]{3}:-)`

Comment: Using a word boundary makes "400:-" return false.

Comment: Strange, in the link you provided "400:-" returns true but in my console application using that same pattern returns false...

Comment: If it's possible to use assertions you could do this. [See example](http://regex101.com/r/bE1tM8)

Comment: It works. I believe its my 3rd party program that cannot make the regex tó work. I will check out why.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression does work, just remove the optional quantifier `?` and place your beginning/ending line anchors outside of your capturing group. It could be simplified to the following.

```
^([0-9]{3}:-)$
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it without the "^" sign?

Comment: only want to match the 3-digits followed by the signs ":-"

Comment: Well if you remove the anchors, it will also match your other ones that you do not want matched.